# Crystal Reports 10 - Adding new fields to a report causes all the fields in my report to disappear

Tags: crystal-reports

I added 2 additional databases to my report(Emp and Unemp).  I verified all the links and they were correct.  The problem is "when I add the new fields (from the new databases) to the report, all of the fields in my report disappear." This disappearing occurs in while in preview. Also, when I remove the newly added fields all of the fields in the report reappear.  Can someone please help?

Answer (score 1):

So, you had a working Crystal Report that originally pulled from 1 table.  Then you added 2 new tables and all your records disappear. Are you sure that the new tables (Emp and Unemp) are populated? Are they joined correctly to your main table?

Just because Crystal tries to auto-link tables for you when you add them doesn't mean you should trust it to do the job correctly.  It might have added some extra joins that don't belong there.

Answer (score 0):

Check your joins and record selection criteria. Something there is causing zero records to be pulled (look at lower right portion of window for Records Read).

You might also do a Database, Verify Database to verify the database is "synced" with the report.